# Is there a way to enable autocomplete in eclipse for programming Go

Tags: eclipse, go, goclipse

I am programming in go using eclipse and I want to enable autocomplete, but I didn't find a way to do this. I use Windows 64-bit.

Comment: Please try the new Goclipse version (0.8.1). It now has a diagnostics/log console for gocode and autocompletion, so that should help pinpoint where the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

The full completion I know of is in [GoSublime](https://github.com/DisposaBoy/GoSublime), a plugin for [SublimeText](http://www.sublimetext.com/3), using [GoCode](https://github.com/nsf/gocode).

For Eclipse, you would need [GoEclipse](http://code.google.com/p/goclipse/) ([GitHub repo](https://github.com/GoClipse/goclipse)) and check if the completion works in that environment. It uses the same GoCode, but has [some issue](https://github.com/GoClipse/goclipse/issues/8).
The completion is supposed to be activated with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

[image: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GoClipse/goclipse/master/documentation/screenshots/main_screenshot-2012.png]